# A query about closing line in mails

Tags: expressions, email

I generally use this sentence at the end my email before signature: 'Please let me know in case of any queries.'

Is this phrase correct to use for closing a mail?

Comment: It would be more usual to say "...if you have any queries", since the reference is to the recipient wanting to ask you a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't feel it is quite correct. "Query" means to ask a question, so it doesn't make sense to ask someone to ask you about a query. It would be like saying "*If you want to ask me anything, please ask me*".

I would write it as:

> Please contact me if you have any queries.

Or a slightly more welcoming version would be:

> Please *feel free* to contact me if you have any queries.

Answer (score 1):

The edited phrase in your question - 'please let me know in case of any queries' - would be suitable for this purpose, since the word query can be synonymous with the word question as a noun, in addition to being a verb referring to asking a question, as Astralbee pointed out.

In addition I'd like to add that the word query is often used in Indian English, but much less frequently used in American English. In my experience in the United States, the word query is very seldom used as a noun, even in formal contexts. I most often see it used in the technical context of querying computer databases.

This national variation is somewhat similar to the differing usage of the word doubt. I've heard many Indian people use doubt in place of the word question, but I've literally never heard anyone from any other culture say, "I have a doubt about the assignment," or something similar. I'm not saying one custom is better than the other, it's just something people should be cognizant of if they're trying to blend-in when in the states.